# what steps to follow new disk space is added to linux platform?

Tags: hard-drive, redhat-enterprise-linux

I am trying to learn Linux environment. I have a VM based on RHEL 6.6 64-bit. One of the system engineers told me he added 20GB disk space to the VM. If I want to use that disk space properly what steps I should follow?

My intention is mount the given disk space to the existing file system (root?) then install software on it such as IBM BPM.

[update]

output of fdisk -l

[image: output 1]

[image: output 2]

---

I am sorry this statement doesn't answer my question. I just need a space to add more files requested. I don't have enough stars to add more than 2 files on my original post.

@David: I add here 4 files of screen shots of lvdisplay and mount commands output.

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Are you using traditional or LVM partitions?

Comment: Forgive me. For now I do not understand difference between two but based on what I've reading. I have a feeling that LVM partitions.

Comment: Can you post the output of `fdisk -l`

Comment: Hi David, Thank you for looking into this matter. I'd appreciate it. I just attached screen shots of running the given command.  It has 8 logical Vol. I think...

Comment: Okay...one last request.  Can you post the outputs of `lvdisplay` and `mount`.  Also, which logical volume do you want the space added to?  I assume from your original post you want it added to the one mounted at `/`?

Comment: I am not sure which logical volume I need to use. All I know is 20 GB is added. I remember one thing that I should not install software under root partition b/c it will use up space quickly. I was told by linux engineer that create a separate partition and format it and install the software then mount it to the root.

Answer (score 0):

It goes without saying that you should follow these instructions at your own risk.  This *should* work but I'm not actually doing these commands as I type them here so if I miss a step or get one wrong, my apologies.  Okay...Here goes.

1. Backup your system.  This is a VM so I would make sure you take a snapshot but have a backup as well.
2. You can't expand the root filesystem live so you'll need to boot to a Live CD.  Take your pick on with one buy my preference is www.sysresccd.org
3. The partition used for LVM is `/dev/sda2` you'll need to delete this and re-create it. Note from the original `fdisk -l` that it starts at sector 502.  Don't worry, your data should be fine, you're only changing entries in the partition table

   `fdisk /dev/sda # note this is /dev/sda NOT /dev/sda2
   d              # delete
   2              # the second partition
   n              # create a new partition
   p              # primary
   2              # this is the second partition
   502            # start at sector 502
                  # press enter to accept the defaults for the end sector
   t              # change the volume type
   2              # on the second volume
   8e             # set the type to 'Linux LVM'
   w              # save your changes and quit fdisk`
4. Now you need to resize the LVM physical volume.

   `pvresize /dev/sda2`
5. Finally, resize the logical volume.  It's a little difficult for me to tell which LV you want the space added to but I'm guessing it's `LogVol00`.  If you run the `mount` command it'll list the devices that's mounted at `/` which is what you want to add the space to.  It'll be in the form of `/dev/mapper/VolGroup00-LogVolxx` where the 'xx' is a number.  Use that device in the following command.

   `lvresize -L+20G --resizefs /dev/mapper/VolGroup00-LogVolxx`

If all went well you should be able to reboot and have an expanded filesystem!  Good luck :)

Comment: Thank you for sharing your knowledge and even willing to help me a stranger in this regards. I am well aware of the risk. I won't blame anyone except for me if it goes wrong. Hope this opportunity I take as a stepping stone for me to have an inch deeper experience in Linux environment. Have a blessed day!

Answer (score 0):

You can follow this approach to seamlessly  increase your root partition after increasing disk size in VMWare.

1. Take a snapshot!
2. Grow the filesystem:

> `fdisk /dev/sda`
>
> `d: delete LVM partition (#2 in your case)`
>
> `n: add primary partition (default values)`
>
> `t: set type to LVM (8e)`
>
> `w: save`

3. Restart server*
4. `pvresize /dev/sda2` Resize LVM physical volume.
5. `lvresize -l +100%FREE /dev/mapper/VolGroup00-LogVol00` Resize the root LV to use all available free space.
6. `resize2fs /dev/mapper/VolGroup00-LogVol00` Resize the root ext4 filesystem.

* you can avoid restarting server if you rescan your SCSI as follows:

Check name of your device: `ls /sys/class/scsi_device/`

Replace the '0:0:0:0′ with the actual scsi bus name: `echo 1 > /sys/class/scsi_device/0\:0\:0\:0/device/rescan`

Comment: Thank you for your input. It helped me to understand what i was trying to do better.